# how to add a text label on the chart base on timestamp and text on spreadsheet

Tags: html, pine-script

I want to add text label on the chart of the tqqq, base on the trading record from the spreadsheet timestamp, share and price. is that possible? and how?
attach is the example that i enter manually.
thanks.[example of how i want the text label on chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRjce.png)

[timestamp spreadsheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odo68.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, as far as I know.

However, you can use the ***Strategy Tester*** for that if you convert your indicator into a strategy.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have to look into other ideas. a lot of new thing to learn.